# combobox item selected To be fixed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I had a databound combobox in my windows form I populate it by a function deptload() IN FORM LOAD

```
public void DeptcomboLoad()
        {
            DataTable dt = depttrans.getDeptName();
            Cmb_Department.DataSource = dt;
            Cmb_Department.DisplayMember = "DepartmentName"; //CHAR
            Cmb_Department.ValueMember = "DepartmentPK"; //INT 
        }
```

Now when an employee of a department (say accounts  DepartmentName="Accounts " , DepartmentPK=23 ) login I want the ComboBox text to be selected as "acounts "
and when I go to get the selected value of the ComboBox I should get 23

I tried

```
Cmb_Department.selectedtext="Accounts"
Cmb_Department.Text="Accounts"
```

but its not giving the selected value

Can anyone give a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change selected value of the combobox you can use
`SelectedItem` property or `SelectedIndex`.
Index must be exact number in your data sourse, and Item must be exact object from datasource

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to put a value INTO the combobox, try to GET the `SelectedItem` like this:

```
string txt= Cmb_Department.SelectedItem.Text
```

or just:

```
string txt= Cmb_Department.SelectedText
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to select the right item by issuing something like this:

```
Cmb_Department.SelectedValue = 23;
```

**Where 23 comes from some other variable, maybe on another object, maybe from a local variable, whatever works in your case.**

Now, to get the selected value you can use this statement:

```
var val = Cmb_Department.SelectedValue;
```

To get the selected text (which would be the text associated with the value):

```
var text = ((DataRow)Cmb_Department.SelectedItem)["DepartmentName"];
```

The reason I'm prescribing the aforementioned is because the `SelectedText` property is volatile, and the `Text` property doesn't always work based on how the `DropDownStyle` is set.

However, some would probably argue to get the same as the aforementioned you could issue this statement:

```
var text = Cmb_Department.Text;
```